# User-defined guards not working anymore?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

The following code was working before the typescript 2.0:

```
class Aluno{
  escola: string;
  constructor(public nome: string){
    this.escola = "";
  }
}
class Pessoa{
  morada: string;
  constructor(public nome: string){
    this.morada = "";
  }
}
function ePessoa(p: Pessoa | Aluno): p is Pessoa{
  return (<Pessoa>p).morada !== undefined;
}
function eAluno(p: Pessoa | Aluno): p is Aluno{
  return (<Aluno>p).escola !== undefined; 
}
let a: Pessoa | Aluno = new Pessoa("Luis");
console.log( a.nome ); //ok
a = new Aluno("Rui");
console.log( a.nome ); //ok
//a.escola = "teste";//erro
if(eAluno(a)){
  console.log("Aluno da escola:" + a.escola);
}
else{
  console.log("Pessoa residente em: " + a.morada); //morada does not exist
}
```

The compiler doesn't seem to consider a as being Pessoa in the else branch. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact error is:

> Property 'morada' does not exist on type 'never'

And the reason you're getting it is because the compiler is smart enough to see that the else part is never accessed.

You're doing:

```
let a: Pessoa | Aluno = new Pessoa("Luis");
...
a = new Aluno("Rui");
```

So when you get to the if it will be `Aluno` for sure, it will never be `Pessoa`.

Here more about the [never type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/release-notes/typescript-2.0.html#the-never-type).

---

#### Edit

It's important that the compiler will restrict the devloper from doing something that is wrong.
Many javascript developers will argue that typescript is reduandent, no need for types, but still you're here using it.

The error you received is important as `Unreachable code` error:

```
function fn(): boolean {
    return false;

    let a = 3; // Error: Unreachable code detected
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20fn()%3A%20boolean%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20false%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20let%20a%20%3D%203%3B%20%2F%2F%20Error%3A%20Unreachable%20code%20detected%0A%7D))

Why would you want to have code parts that are never executed?
It's just like not having them plus the trouble of maintaining them with code and changes, and taking them into account when working on the code.

---

#### 2nd edit

The compiler doesn't check that for the entire flow, so you'll get the error messages only if the compiler detects it in the current scope.
Same with `Unreachable code` error:

```
function fn(): boolean {
    throw new Error("error");
}

let a = fn();
if (a) { // no error
    console.log("all good");
}
```

But:

```
let a = fn();
throw new Error("error");
if (a) { // Error: Unreachable code detected
    console.log("all good");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nitzan. Absolutely right. Interesting, wrapping the creation in a simple method that returns Aluno | Pessoa removes the error...which, IMO, shouldn't really be there...

Comment: Hello again.
What I'm saying is that we're missing coherence. So, when using a = new Aluno(...), the compiler generates an error. I can live with that. But if you write something like a = (():Pessoa|Aluno=>new Aluno(...))() then the error goes away...